# Inverse of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, inverse-function

I'm trying to invert a function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ and don't know where to begin, for example suppose this one $$\alpha(t)=(\cos t,\operatorname{sen} t,t),$$
does it have inverse? How can i get to $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ or $\alpha(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$? I thought of things like the one below, but I don't know how to proceed.
$$
\begin{array}
tt=\cos^{-1}x\\
t=\operatorname{sen}^{-1}y\\
t=z
\end{array}
$$
How can I unify these equations or even check if the inverse really works?

Comment: Your function $\alpha$ is not *onto*, for example, there is no $t$ such that $\alpha(t)=(0,0,0)$, so there can't possibly be an inverse defined on all of ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: I want to define the inverse in some way, guessing the domain of the inverse as the alpha image or something.

Comment: Then the inverse of $\alpha$ is $\beta(x,y,z)=z$ (but only on the image of $\alpha$).